# Do not refresh data on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radio button list that requires a selection (Autopostback = true) and then it loads data from a service into a listbox. The data is loaded into the listbox on a selectedIndexChanged event.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblMyList" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem>Option 1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Option 3</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

That data pull can take a few seconds to pull the data.

My problem is that when clicking the Submit button, it actually loads the data from the service again and then does the postback. I don't want this, it's making the submit take longer and there is no need because the data is already there.

How can I bypass that reloading of data?

Comment: in page load - if (!Page.IsPostBack) {initialload();}

Comment: -1 The bit of HTML that you included is not enough to troubleshoot the problem. You'll have to post the `rbl_SelectedIndexChanged` handler code, plus the `Page_Load` code and any other code in the event handlers.

Comment: Presumably you'd wrap your server-side code in a conditional of some sort to determine whether or not the code therein should be executed.  Of course, without knowing anything about that code, all anybody can do here is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if IsPostBack

```
If(Page.IsPostback)
{ 
    return;
}
```

but you should do this in ur change index thing I think

Comment: Hmm but the problem is if I do that it will not load the data at all. It needs a first postback so it knows a value was selected on the radio button list.

Comment: You could check if the listbox contains value